# Как решить проблему 'Зависит: X но он не будет установлен'?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, зависимости

Есть не очень то шарящий в вопросе юзер и желание накатить драйвера. Делаем по инструкции с вики, но на

> Установите соответствующий пакет linux-headers и пакет модуля ядра

Возникает определенный затык:

```
root@debian:/home/keddad# apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-driver
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 nvidia-driver : Зависит: nvidia-driver-libs (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: nvidia-driver-bin (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: nvidia-vdpau-driver (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) но он не будет установлен
                 Зависит: nvidia-alternative (= 375.82-1~deb9u1)
                 Зависит: nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) или
                                 nvidia-kernel-375.82
                 Рекомендует: nvidia-settings (>= 375) но он не будет установлен
                 Рекомендует: nvidia-persistenced
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Как это можно решить? Гугл не помог :(

Comment: Я не специалист, но если вы будете искать в гугле `название_пакета  deb` выберете нужный пакет, скачаете, а потом выполните `dpkg -i название_файла.deb`, то эти проблемы будут устранены

Comment: И да, я бы переименовал вопрос в `Как решить проблему 'Зависит: X но он не будет установлен'?`. Это хороший вопрос, но он не только о драйверах nvidia. Дайте возможность другим легче находить ваш вопрос :)

Comment: Обычно помогает попросить aptitude установить соответствующий пакет, после чего он сообщит, в чем конфликт

Comment: Простое решение, как уже сказано — разрешить конфликт aptitude'ом... Объяснение, почему так произошло крутится вокруг замены проприетарной libdispatch0-nvidia (в stretch) на открытую libglvnd0 (в buster'е)... Подозреваю, что у ТС неумелое смешение ветвей.

Comment: Тут больший набор вариантов исправления: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/947695)

Comment: Встречал такую же ошибку при установке mongdb. Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть нужные репозитории. В моем случае, когда я добавил правильный репозитори, все встало как надо.

Comment: А может всё-таки попробовать через driver manager поставить? Или его там нет?

Answer (score 0):

Добавь через пробел то от чего оно там зависит. Возможно надо еще указать откуда взять правильную версию через `-t`  ( `-t stretch-backports`)

aptitude иногда лучше решает зависимости и предлагает варианты. Попробуйте через этот пакетный менеджер.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы сделал `apt install -f`

Если не сработало, то искал бы эти пакеты в репозиториях Debian, как `nvidia-driver-libs deb`.
Вот, к примеру ваш [nvidia-driver-libs](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/nvidia-driver-libs)

Если скачать версию для х64, то название файла будет `nvidia-driver-libs_375.82-1_deb9u1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb`.

А потом просто устанавливаем его:

`dpkg -i nvidia-driver-libs_375.82-1_deb9u1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb`

Comment: `Распаковывается nvidia-driver-libs:amd64 (375.82-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1) …
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет nvidia-driver-libs:amd64:
 nvidia-driver-libs:amd64 зависит от libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx (= 375.82-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1) | libgl1-nvidia-glx (= 375.82-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1), однако:
  Пакет libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx не установлен.
  Пакет libgl1-nvidia-glx не установлен.
 nvidia-driver-libs:amd64 зависит от nvidia-egl-icd (= 375.82-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1) | libegl1-nvidia (= 375.82-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1), однако:
  Пакет nvidia-egl-icd не установлен.
  Пакет libegl1-nvidia не установлен.
`

Comment: Это после какой команды?

Comment: Если я все эти зависимости сделаю вручную, я не столкнусь еще с сотней другой ошибок?

Comment: `dpkg -i nvidia-driver-libs_375.82-1_deb9u1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb`

Comment: @biryulin04 хочется тут вставить песню Guns N' Roses - Welcome To The Jungle :D Решение с `dpkg` довольно низкоуровневое. Возможно, что есть другие варианты. Вам в коментариях выше подсказали с `aptitude`. Возможно, стоит попробовать с ним, если с `dpkg` слишком сложно

Comment: Окей, пойду пробовать, а то выяснил что там уже Содом и Гоморра: даже apt --fix-broken install выдает странные ошибки

Comment: Но из вашей ошибки выше вы, наверное, уже поняли, что нужно проделать ту же операцию из ответа с пакетом `libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx`

Comment: два десятка пакетов качать и вручную и зависимости с альтернативами для них разруливать самостоятельно — это не то что низкоуровневое решение, а скорее уже жест отчаяния ;)...